# Issues with HTML Encoding in ASP.NET Core MVC web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, nuget

I just started at a new job as a senior .NET developer, and have run into a very puzzling issue with the package System.Text.Encodings.Web.

The project is in .NET Framework 4.6.1

The package is showing in the NUGET PACKAGE MANAGER as Installed version 4.5.0, however, the using statement in a .CS file that is trying to use the HtmlEncoder is showing an error with the error text "The type or namespace 'Encodings' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Text'. Are you missing an assembly reference?"

It also says after trying to build, another error, "The type HtmlEncoder is defined in an assembly that is not referenced, You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Text.Encodings.Web, version=4.0.3, Culture=neutral, and then a public key token after that."

I tried several different things but none of them worked.

Comment: So is it .Net core or .Net 4.6, or a mix?

Comment: It is a mix actually, the main project is MVC .NET Core 2.1, with some needed libraries in some other projects in the solution and this project which is having the problems is in .NET framework 4.6.1

Comment: Sounds like a 'delete your bin and obj directories and restart visual studio' problem to me.

Comment: I believe I am going to try to update Visual Studio to most recent version, I had a problem with Visual Studio before and updating fixed the issue, Visual Studio updates always have bug fixes in them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the same problem in a NUnitTest project which referenced the main project (both netcorapp2.1).

I have solved the problem by copying the below Package References from the main project into the test project (.csproj files):

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.1.2" PrivateAssets="All" />
```